# Getting Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined with promise

Tags: node.js, promise

Okay, I can't figure this one out.   When I run the below code where 'test' function calls the 'getData()'

```
getData() {
  let hs = new HubSpotClient({ hapikey: '12345' });
    hs.contacts.getById(2401)
      .then(results => {
    console.log('results: ' + JSON.stringify(results))
    return result;
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('err: ' + err)
  });
},


function test () {
  return this.getData().then(res => {
    console.log(res);
    return res;
  })
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

If I get rid of the .then and only have return this.getData(), then the getData() does not return a result as if it wasn't even evoked.  I tried async / await, but the testing framework I'm using doesn't allow it.

Comment: return the promise from the function, it should be `...return hs.contacts...`

Comment: Thanks, but when I add ...return hs.contacts... it doesn't return.   It gets to a break point of the .then in the line below and doesn't make it to the break point on the line below that.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, it should work.

Comment: maybe providing more details could help.

Comment: make some edits about what returning 'hs.contacts'  did, what were the changes observed. That'd be helpful.